# Add property of each element in array to a new array

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to create a products database system. In CakePHP, I have an array of all products in the 'products' table. Each product (an element in the 'products' array) has a function 'toArray()'. This converts the product into an associative array. How could I take an array of all the products and add the 'toArray()' of each product to a new array. This is my current flow:

```
$products = [$product1, $product2, $product3];
$newArr = [];
foreach($products as $product) {
    $newArr[] = $product->toArray();
}
```

Is there a one-liner for something like this?

Comment: thanks @quickshiftin, that went right over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you could quite oneline this (without functionalizing it, anyway), but you don't need to duplicate data unless you need to keep the original format as well as the reformatted version.

```
foreach($products as $key => $product){
    $products[$key] = $product->toArray();
}
```

Will change your exisiting array to the reformatted version.